# Finding user that have at least one tag object in linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have an object User.

```
User 1..N Tags(string).
```

For instance, i have a List of Tag object. How can i query the User to find all the user that have at least 1 Tag in side the list of tags?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code snippet means you have a property `Tags` of type `Foo<string>` where `Foo` is some sequence type, you could just use:

```
var taggedUsers = users.Where(user => tags.Any(tag => user.Tags.Contains(tag));
```

(Actually, that's assuming you have a list of *strings* as `Tags` - the question is somewhat unclear. However, hopefully it'll be enough to sort you out.)

EDIT: Okay, with the details in the comments, I think you probably just need:

```
var taggedUsers = users.Where(user => tags.Any(tag => user.Tags
                                                          .Select(t => t.Value)
                                                          .Contains(tag));
```

Comment: How about if Tags are objects? sorry for not being clear :) Thank you Jon.

Comment: @DucDigital: Does the Tag object have any notion of equality on it? What's in the database for the user - strings or tags?

Comment: In the database, User object has many Tags object, each tag object has a ID and a string "Value". I have currently a list of string that are possible tags to query.

Comment: {"Must specify parameter on right side of operation. ({1})"} I got the ff. exception. Couldn't figure out a way. But maybe I will go straight to raw sql.

Comment: @DucDigital: With no more information than that? I wouldn't expect to see {1} in the exception message...